# For loop calculate time between timestamps

Tags: r

So, I absolutely suck at loops (if you have any recommended documentation to practice it more, please let me know). However, at the moment I'd like to calculate the time difference between timestamps for each instance and the instance before (for a few 100,000 instances). To illustrate (dataset 'test'):

```
car name     timestamp
1            2015-05-03 21:15:00
1            2015-05-03 21:45:00
1            2015-05-03 22:30:00
2            2015-05-04 05:45:00
2            2015-05-04 16:45:00
```

Timestamp is in POSIXct format. What I want to achieve, is that the loop calculates for every car the time difference in minutes with the instance before, as long as it is the same car. So, I'd like to get the following results:

```
[1] N/A
[2] 30
[3] 45
[4] N/A
[5] 660
```

I managed to calculate the time between two instances with:

```
difftime(test$timestamp[3],test$timestamp[(3-1)],units="mins")
```

I started placing it in a loop as follows:

```
for(i in test$timestamp){
minparked<-difftime(test$timestamp[i],test$timestamp[i-1],units="mins") 
}
```

But this one gives me errors, plus I have to tell it not to calculate time difference for the first row of a new car (so row [1] and [4] for example).

Thank you so much in advance for helping me out!

Comment: This seems like a great case for avoiding a loop. Is there any reason you really want one?

Comment: Nop! Just thought it would be the best way.. but really happy not to use one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a double for loop will be alright.

```
output <- c()
for(car in unique(test$carName)){
  tmp <- test[test$carName==car,]
  out <- c(NA)
  for(j in 2:nrow(tmp)){
    out[j] <- difftime(tmp$timestamp[j],tmp$timestamp[j-1],units="mins") 
  }
  output <- c(output, out)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, this does not overcome the fact that there are many different car names, not just one (above is an extract of the data, there are about 700 different car names).

Comment: The code is written especially for that. The purpose of the line "for(car in unique(test$carName)){" is to select the subset of your data for each car. No matter the number of different car names

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, didn't read it well enough! Thanks so much, this one is working!!

Comment: You're welcome, but keep in mind for loops are not the best way to run a code fast in R. I'm not well documented about other ways to do that except for functions as lapply, sapply and vapply. But if your data is not really big, running a for loop is enough i think.